# Cлушатель событий onclick вызывает функцию дважды

Tags: javascript, события, onclicklistener

```js
function tagPageSorting(form) {
  //Sort bookCards on tag page using fetch ajax
  
  form.onclick = () => {
    console.log("work");
  }
}

tagPageSorting(document.getElementById('tagSort'));
```

```html
<form class="tag-sort noselect" id="tagSort">
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-created_at" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-1" checked><label for="sort-1">Дате<br>загрузки</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="title" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-2"><label for="sort-2">Имени</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-chapters" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-3"><label for="sort-3">Количеству<br>глав</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-rate" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-4"><label for="sort-4">Рейтингу</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-comments" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-5"><label for="sort-5">Количеству<br>комментариев</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста поделиться минимальным исполняемым кодом в `Code Snippet`-е пожалуйста? Потому что у меня он вызывается 1 раз, может быть чего-то не учёл, буду очень признателен!

Comment: https://codepen.io/kurtzalexo/pen/MWrJdmv?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли напсиать `e.preventDefault();`:

```js
function tagPageSorting(form) {
  // Sort bookCards on tag page using fetch ajax
  
  form.onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("work")
  }
}

tagPageSorting(document.getElementById('tagSort'));
```

```html
<form class="tag-sort noselect" id="tagSort">
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-created_at" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-1" checked><label for="sort-1">Дате<br>загрузки</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="title" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-2"><label for="sort-2">Имени</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-chapters" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-3"><label for="sort-3">Количеству<br>глав</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-rate" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-4"><label for="sort-4">Рейтингу</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sort" value="-comments" class="tag-sort__option" id="sort-5"><label for="sort-5">Количеству<br>комментариев</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Тогда не переключаються радио кнопки.

Comment: В общем добавил data атрибут к каждому input и проверку if (e.target.dataset.input == 'true') {        console.log('work')} и все заработало. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AlexKutz я правильно понимаю, что вы при нажатии на `form` хотите по выбранному `radio` сделать запрос? Если это так то вы в корне неправильно работаете с формой, вам надо обрабатывать его событие `submit`, а не `click`